# multiple Git SSH KEY

Tags: ssh, git

**I have some question about multiple git-ssh-key**

**I want to know**

- I have created a git-ssh key host for each repository(same git account). Is it right?
- I had better create a [rsa_github] file for each repository.

**config file**

```
Host github-git
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/[rsa_github]
    User git
Host github-git-secondary
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/[rsa_github]
    User git
```

everything is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to create one ssh private and public key for each user for authenticating via ssh with github.

There is no need to create a new ssh key for each repository you own (only each login)